# Viewpager with fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in my app with 7 fragments, each represent their own logic

however, there are 2 fragments that are mutually coupled, one cannot exist without the other.

I have 2 buttons, previous and next at the bottom of the screen which switch between the fragments.

I want to make it so the swiping in the viewpager cannot reach one of the coupled fragments

Right now I did this: I put the first fragment (of the coupled ones) to be at location 0, and the 2nd fragment at the last position, so that when you swipe left and right you reach the 2nd coupled fragment last.

I want to make it so you can't reach the last fragment with swiping

how to do that ?

EDIT:

Fragment Adapter

```
public class PurchaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<BaseFragment> fragments;
private boolean shouldShowLastFragment;
@Inject
public PurchaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void setFragments(List<BaseFragment> fragments) {
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public BaseFragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments == null ? 0 : shouldShowLastFragment ? fragments.size() : fragments.size()-1;
}

public void enableItem(int i) {
    shouldShowLastFragment = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void disableItem(int i) {

    shouldShowLastFragment = false;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Seems to me that you break the purpose of the adapter a bit by implementing setFragments(List<BaseFragment> fragments). Instead you should override getItem(int position) as Erix show in his answer, letting the adapter instantiate the individual fragments. I suspect this is where things goes wrong regarding my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have either a FragmentStatePagerAdapter or a FragmentPagerAdapter.

In your adapter, setting the `getCount()` method to 6, will make sure that you cannot reach the last fragment.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: will i still be able to reach it programmatically, by setCurrentItem(6) ?

Comment: if your getItem(position) method supports it I would think so, yes

Comment: alternatively you could have some logic in the getCount method like `return (shouldShowLastFragment) ? 7 : 6;` to enable/disable the last fragment.

Comment: that doesnt work, unfortunately, once the fragment gets enabled, and you swipe to the last page, if you half swipe after the last page, the last fragment is there and half visible, it wont let that page become selected, but it still shows it

Comment: That sounds odd. It should not allow going beyond the 6th page if getCount returns 6. Would you mind posting the code of your Adapter?

Comment: posted and 15 more characters

Comment: @LenaBru You are right and I've deleted my uncorrect answer. I ditn't think this thoroughly. Thanks for noticing.